# How to concatenate the fields from table values and use it as a column in the select statement

Tags: sql

I created a scripts that dynamically select the columns from the db table and use it as a column in the select statement. However, I encountered an error "Incorrect syntax near Select". Anyone has an idea?

```
Table_Sample_Table
ColumnName-SqlColumnName

SqlColumnName Values 
'Salary'
Age
Name
Address

table_to_query_the_data
Columns consist of
Salary
Age
Name
Address

Sample Query
SET @x='Select ' + SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + SqlColumnName
            FROM sample_table
            WHERE SqlColumnName ='Salary'
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Txt + 'from table_to_query_the_data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are not very clear but I think `SET @x` should be like;

```
SET @x= 'SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + SqlColumnName
         FROM sample_table
         WHERE SqlColumnName = 'Salary'
         FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')   + ' FROM table_to_query_the_data'
```

Or you better wrap your column names with `[]` as `[col1],[col2],..`

```
SET @x= 'SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT '],[' + SqlColumnName
         FROM sample_table
         WHERE SqlColumnName = 'Salary'
         FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,2,'')  + '] FROM table_to_query_the_data'
```